# Is there a limit on how many rows LoopbackJS/Oracle can retrieve using the REST API?

Tags: node.js, oracle, api, rest, loopbackjs

I am using LoopbackJS and Oracle Database. In the GET APIs, I am able to retrieve a maximum of **3000** results as Array in response. Is there any way to increase the fetch size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loopback, the `server/datasources.json` file has a `db` object, in which the `maxRows` property is for defining the maximum limit to retrieve from the database(using oracledb npm). The default value is 3000.
[Refer here](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-3213-oracledbmaxrows)